# Problems with adding FileUpload from PrimeVue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3, primevue

I had a project on Vue 3. Wanted to add some tags from PrimeVue. Installed it vue npm, add code to main.js:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config';
import FileUpload from 'primevue/fileupload';
import TextArea from 'primevue/textarea';

const app = createApp(App);

Vue.use(VAnimateCss);

app.use(PrimeVue);
app.component('FileUpload', FileUpload);
app.component('TextArea', TextArea);
```

And used that tags in my .vue page.
For template part:

```
<div class="form-post__form">
            <Textarea id="new-title" rows="1" v-model="newTitle" placeholder="Title"/>
            <Textarea id="new-post" rows="7" v-model="newPost" placeholder="Tell us latest news"/>
            <Textarea id="new-photo" rows="1" v-model="newPhoto" placeholder="PPhoto"/>
            <FileUpload name="demo[]" url="./upload" :multiple="true" />
        </div>
```

In the script tag:

```
import Textarea from 'primevue/textarea';
import FileUpload from 'primevue/fileupload';

export default {
    name: 'FormPost',
    components: {
        Textarea,
        FileUpload,
    },
```

I have no errors, but the page is blank. Once i comment tags, things work again. Whats the problem?